# clicking on one uibutton in custom uitableviewcell selects multiple uibuttons in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've a uitableview in childViewController of a uiviewcontroller. Inside that uitableview, I've used custom uitableviewcell. In that custom uitableviewcell, I have favorite checkbox button.

This uitableview contains about 30 records and about 10 records appear on visible screen, then on scroll another 10, and then another.

The problem is when I select a uibutton on 1st row, and then scroll down the uitableview, I see it selected on 11th and 21st row as well. I'm on it for half day now, but couldn't spot the issue. Any help please.

Here is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ABCViewCell *cell = (ABCViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ABCViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.delegate = self;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
cell.labelDesiredDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
cell.labelJournaledDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

return cell; }
```

Thanks,
Abdul

Comment: Please post code for your table view's cellForRowAtIndexPath. Sounds like you are reusing table cells (good) but not preparing them for reuse properly.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've added cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that as you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method, your cell is begin recicle for drawing all of your content. So you must consider a way of cleaning your data.

Something as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ABCViewCell *cell = (ABCViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ABCViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self shouldMyCellBeSelected]) {
        [cell displayButtonSelected];
    } else {
        [cell displayButtonUnselected];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

1. *shouldMyCellBeSelected*. Your should have a function for determining if the specific cell at a
   given position should be selected. You can do that by having a
   separate list of indexes of the user cells selection and comparing the
   current to-be-draw-cell to see if it's on that list.
2. *displayButtonSelected/displayButtonUnselected*. Then you should have a function for displaying your cell Selected and also Unselected. That can be by changing images of your button or activating/deactivating it.

Hope that helps